# COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN looking for function not column? MySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax

Ok. I'm about to give up on this one.

When I run the following query, I get "Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION statpurchase.playerId does not exist". I don't get a line number, but I strongly suspect the COUNT(DISTINCT(WHEN clauses.

The query is attempting to compute the percent of unique playerIds who make a purchase in a given day for a range of time. statpurchase.playerId is a valid column name.

It's a poor man who blames his tools, but I suspect its possibly a parser error similar to [this one](http://blog.152.org/2009/12/mysql-error-1305-function-xxx-does-not.html).

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `percentUniquesPurchasing`(in startTime datetime, in endTime datetime, in placeId int)
BEGIN

declare total_uniques int;
declare iOS_uniques int;
declare desktop_uniques int;
declare i datetime;
set i = startTime;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results (
    theday datetime, 
    total float,
    iOS float,
    desktop float
);



while(i < endTime + INTERVAL 1 DAY) do



    select count(distinct(statplaysession.playerId)), 
        count(distinct(case when touchInterface = 1 then statplaysession.playerId else null end)),
        count(distinct(case when touchInterface = 0 then statplaysession.playerId else null end))
    into
        total_uniques, iOS_uniques, desktop_uniques
    from rbxstats.statplaysession 
    where
        statplaysession.start > i and
        statplaysession.start < i + INTERVAL 1 DAY and
        statplaysession.placeId = placeId;

    insert into results (theday, total, iOS, desktop) 
    select i, 
            if(total_uniques > 0, count(distinct(statpurchase.playerId)) / total_uniques, 0), 
            if(iOS_uniques > 0, count(distinct(statpurchase.playerId(case when touchInterface = 1 then statpurchase.playerId end))) / iOS_uniques, 0), 
            if(desktop_uniques > 0, count(distinct(statpurchase.playerId(case when touchInterface = 0 then statpurchase.playerId end))) / desktop_uniques,0)
    from rbxstats.statpurchase where
        statpurchase.timestamp > i and
        statpurchase.timestamp < i + INTERVAL 1 DAY and
        statpurchase.placeId = placeId;


    set i = i + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
end while;

select * from results;
drop temporary table results;
END$$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on these 2 lines you try to use statpurchase.playerId as a function, which it doesnt seem to be, its a column in your table

```
 if(iOS_uniques > 0, count(distinct(statpurchase.playerId(case when 
 if(desktop_uniques > 0, count(distinct(statpurchase.playerId(case when
```